# Backbone - leave app and return renders no view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am quite new to backbone and have an issue I can't seem to resolve or find a solution.

I have backbone on my site. We are using backbone on part of the site, on a route '/route#...'

It works great and renders all views but when I leave this route and go to another page, for example the homepage, but then return to the backbone app no view is rendered.

I have to then refresh the page manually.

I have tried to end the backbone history and have ensured my JS files arent being requested twice.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

router setup:

```
queriesToolApp.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
   "all"      : "index",          // /queries listings view
   "new"      : "new",            // /queries new report view
   "show/:id" : "show"            // individual get a new report show page
  },
  index: function() {
    // Create a new instance of the queries collection
    var queries = new queriesToolApp.Queries();
    // Make a GET request and send the data to the view
    queries.fetch({
      success: function(reports) {
        // On success render the view
        var allReportsView = new queriesToolApp.AllReportsView({collection: reports});
        // render the view
        allReportsView.render();
      }
    })
  },
  new: function() {
    // Create a new instance of the Account List Collection
    var accountList = new queriesToolApp.AccountList();
    // Grab the data from API
    accountList.fetch({
      success: function(accounts) {
        // On success render the view
        var accountListView = new queriesToolApp.AccountListView({collection: accounts});
        // render the view
        accountListView.render();
      }
    })
  },
  show: function(id) {
    // create a new instance of the existing report and pass in the id
    var report = new queriesToolApp.Query({id: id});
    //  grab 'this' context and call AJAX to get existing report data
    report.fetch({
      success: function(report){
        // Create a new instance of the report keyword view
        var reportKeywordView = new queriesToolApp.ReportKeywordsView({collection: report});
        // Render the view
        reportKeywordView.render();
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your route setup look like?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Also check to see if you render methods clear up the container at the begining.